# Creating extension failed: waiting for unix socket to be available: context deadline exceeded

Tags: osquery

When i call the funciton osquery.NewExtensionManagerServer i get error:
Waiting for unix socket to be available /var/osquery/oq.em context deadline exceeded

i am on linux RHEL 8.2. Haven't seen on other linux version.
What might be the issue. any pointers will help.

I was expecting that the unix socket will be created and getting logger callback

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How is the extension being started? Is osquery starting it, or are you starting it on your own outside osquery?

Comment: were you able to fix it ? I'm facing the same  issue and no end in sight

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are seeing this error on RHEL and not other Linux versions, I am going to guess there is some issue with SELinux permissions.

Does osquery have permissions to open a unix domain socket (check the logs for any errors)?

Does your extension have permissions to open a unix domain socket?

Comment: Thanks for the pointers...I have disabled SELinux using setenforce 0, so now SELinux is in permissive mode but still getting same error....also I tried by rebooting the system but same error

Comment: Are you running both osquery and the extension as root?

Comment: Yes I am running both osquery and extension as root.